# Numbers of threads running

Tags: java, executorservice

I am curious with the codes below. Assuming i have a main() method running the code below. What is the maximum amount of threads that can be ran with the code below?

```
ExecutorService ex= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
 for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            RunnableTask task = new RunnableTask(i, 3);
            ex.submit(task);
        }
```

Will the answer be 4? Since i have a main thread with another 3 threads as the ExecutorService only permits a maximum of 3 threads to be ran?

Comment: Logically there would be `n <= 1 (main) + size(fixed pool)` so there will be less than or equal to 4 threads at a time.

Comment: You'll get 3 threads generated in thread pool. Another 2 threads, that you submit will wait until one of first 3 threads stop.

Answer (score 4):

According to official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)http://) .

> If additional tasks are submitted when all threads are active, they
>   will wait in the queue until a thread is available. If any thread
>   terminates due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new
>   one will take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks. The
>   threads in the pool will exist until it is explicitly shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are submitting 5 times but you have only fixed 3 thread which will exceute your 5 submitted tasks

Well demostrated By @James Jithin,
Defeniatly you have other suporting/helper thread which has there own task apart from your worker thread, To worker thread you will assign some task and these thread are only resposible to do there assigned task other managmnet other task will be assigne to helper/supporting internal threads.

As demostrated by @James other demon thread has internal  task as below:

1. **Attach Listener:** Dynamic attach has an attach listener thread in the target JVM. This is a thread that is started when the first attach request occurs.
2. **Signal Dispatcher:** When the OS raises a signal to the JVM, the signal dispatcher thread will pass the signal to the appropriate handler.
3. **Reference Handler:** High-priority thread to enqueue pending References. The GC creates a simple linked list of references which need to be processed and this thread quickly adds them to a proper queue and notifies ReferenceQueue listeners.
4. **Finalizer:** The Finalizer thread calls finalizer methods.
5. **main:** It must be the last thread to finish execution. When the main thread stops, your program terminates.

Comment: Yeah, so the maximum threads that can be ran at a time should be 4 right? since main() will have a thread running too.

Answer (score 1):

Let's figure it out:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    class RunnableTask implements Runnable {
        public RunnableTask(int i, int j) {
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    ExecutorService ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        RunnableTask task = new RunnableTask(i, 3);
        ex.submit(task);
    }

    ThreadMXBean threadMXBean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
    System.out.println(threadMXBean.getThreadCount());

    long[] tIds = threadMXBean.getAllThreadIds();
    for (long tId : tIds) {
        System.out.println(threadMXBean.getThreadInfo(tId).getThreadName());
    }

    ex.shutdown();
}
```

My output:

```
8
pool-1-thread-3
pool-1-thread-2
pool-1-thread-1
Attach Listener
Signal Dispatcher
Finalizer
Reference Handler
main
```

The number of worker threads would be 3 as you have defined a fixed thread-pool.